# Retrieve a JSON from postman on PHP

Tags: php, json, forms, laravel

I am trying to retrieve a json from an api (and store as a variable), but I am unable to retrieve.
I am trying in all ways that postman and the web give to me.

1. I Am using laravel/homestead (ubuntu)
2. I am using laravel framework.

This way give me a **HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type**

```
 <?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_PORT => "443",
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://iescities.com:443/IESCities/api/data/query/268/sql?origin=original",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "select * from wifi",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "postman-token: 1471daf9-329d-e9b4-b144-0383850f4769"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

I also try another way but I haven't http\Client class and I haven't idea of how install and/or link it.

```
$client = new http\Client;
$request = new http\Client\Request;

$body = new http\Message\Body;
$body->append('select * from wifi');

$request->setRequestUrl('https://iescities.com:443/IESCities/api/data/query/268/sql');
$request->setRequestMethod('POST');
$request->setBody($body);

$request->setQuery(new http\QueryString(array(
  'origin' => 'original'
)));

$request->setHeaders(array(
  'postman-token' => 'e854f317-fdcc-1888-0043-758a3d5e32ba',
  'cache-control' => 'no-cache'
));

$client->enqueue($request)->send();
$response = $client->getResponse();

echo $response->getBody();
```

Lot of thanks and sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "select * from wifi"` this is one suspect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [IESCities manual](https://iescities.com/IESCities/manual/api-guide/data.html#querying-data):

> Query must be sent in text/plain format.

So in the line you set the headers:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "postman-token: 1471daf9-329d-e9b4-b144-0383850f4769"
),
```

You should put another key:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "postman-token: 1471daf9-329d-e9b4-b144-0383850f4769",
    "Content-Type: text/plain"
),
```

After doing this you should be able to query the API.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried decoding the JSON?

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);

$responseJSON = json_decode($response, true);
print_r($responseJSON);
```

If you JSON looks like:

```
{
    "name": Susy,
    "age": 22
}
```

You can pull the age by using `echo $responseJSON["age"];`